# How to say a number is a long or decimal in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, boxing

You can specify that a number is a double using the below code ('d' letter):

```
 double hi = 12d;
```

How to say a number is a long or decimal?

```
decimal dcml = 12?;
long lng = 12?;
```

Comment: long lng = 12L; decimal dcn = 12m;

Answer (score 8):

The type suffix for long is L
The type suffix for decimal is M

```
decimal dcml = 12M;
long lng = 12L;
```

[This is a simple article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix) as a reference (simple meaning easier to read and digest, not simplistic)
[This is the reference for integers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [for real numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691085%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from the C# Language Specifications

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
decimal dcml = 12M;
long lng = 12L;
```